# Treat class as NoneType python

Tags: python

This might be a long shot but I thought I would try anyway.

Is there anyway to get a class to act like a `NoneType` when it isn't one?

Lets say I have this object in a third party API that I can't change but I can monkey patch onto. Most of the methods can return this object at same stage.  This object is  the same as `None`, as in they decided to use their own custom type to mean the same thing as `None`.

Is it possible at all for me to monkey patch this type so that it will act like None when checked:

```
value = SpecialNoneClass()
if value is None:
   print foobar
```

Comment: You can, but you'll have to implement a `__getattr__` for your class which returns `None`.

Comment: That is fine. I can do that.

Comment: See this question just a few hours old: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18204227/accessing-an-objects-attribute-inside-setattr#comment26682610_18204227

Comment: possible duplicate of [python: class override "is" behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993239/python-class-override-is-behavior)

Comment: Not really a duplicate, considering that post ment to replace `is` and not a object type.

Comment: @Torxed: No, that post is about hooking *into* the `is` operator and make it return `True` for something that is not the same object as the other operand. Which is what the OP is trying to do here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot, because `is` tests for **identity**, not equality. The `value` reference has to point to the *same object* as `None`.

`None` is a singleton object, *and* `None` is a keyword in Python 3, so you cannot make `None` refer to another object either.

Comment: I guess the best I can do is implement `__nonzero__` and return `False`

Comment: That is a better bet; or test against *that* object with `is`: `if value is SpecialNoneClass`. If they are using it as a singleton that'll work just fine.

Comment: `"If they are using it as a singleton that'll work just fine"` unfortunately not. Oh well such as life.